# Compiling Psycopg2 when ./configure postgres --with-openssl failed import module

Tags: python, postgresql, ssl, aws-lambda, psycopg2

I'm trying to compile psycopg2 with ssl enabled for AWS Lambda function as Lambda requires static libpq. However, when I did the step to ./configure postgresql with option --with-openssl everything compiles and make/make install was successful.

But after installing the package when I import psycopg2 in python it gives the error:

undefined symbol: ASN1_STRING_length

I run:
ldd -r /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so

and the result is:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff0e5fb000)
libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x00007fadb7228000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fadb700c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fadb6c49000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fadb6a45000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fadb6842000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fadb653f000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055cf7bfc2000)
undefined symbol: ASN1_STRING_length    
(/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: ASN1_STRING_length    (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-

packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_get_error (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_use_certificate_file  (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: ENGINE_free   (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: sk_free   (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_write (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: OPENSSL_config    (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: sk_value  (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSLv23_method (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_free  (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: X509_STORE_load_locations (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: ENGINE_init   (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file    (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: X509_NAME_ENTRY_get_data  (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: BIO_s_socket  (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: ASN1_STRING_data  (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: CRYPTO_num_locks  (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: X509_get_subject_name (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: ERR_reason_error_string   (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_get_version   (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_set_ex_data   (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_library_init  (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_read  (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_get_current_cipher    (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_CTX_ctrl  (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_new   (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_shutdown  (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: BIO_set_flags (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_use_PrivateKey_file   (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: ERR_clear_error   (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_CIPHER_get_bits   (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_CTX_new   (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: BIO_clear_flags   (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: CRYPTO_get_id_callback    (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_get_peer_certificate  (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: X509_NAME_get_entry   (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: BIO_new   (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: X509_get_ext_d2i  (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_ctrl  (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: X509_STORE_set_flags  (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_pending   (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_set_verify    (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: BIO_int_ctrl  (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: CRYPTO_get_locking_callback   (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: CRYPTO_set_id_callback    (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: X509_free (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: ENGINE_finish (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: X509_NAME_get_index_by_NID    (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: sk_num    (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_use_PrivateKey    (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_connect   (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_load_error_strings    (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: ERR_get_error (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_CTX_get_cert_store    (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_check_private_key (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_CIPHER_get_name   (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: CRYPTO_set_locking_callback   (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: ENGINE_load_private_key   (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: ERR_put_error (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_get_current_compression   (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-
packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: ENGINE_by_id  (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
undefined symbol: SSL_set_bio   (/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so)
```

Could someone help me understand what the problem is?

Thanks!